# get largest eigenvalue with mix of real and complex numbers

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How to rank eigenvalues to pick the largest when some are real and some complex? shall I take its magnitude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lambda_{max}$ is an eigenvalue with the largest absolute value.